# Ubuntu 17.10 LaTeX Beamer + Russian

Tags: apt, latex

I installed 17.10 a couple of days ago, everything works nice except...

I make presentations in latex in Beamer and use Russian language. Of course, I have a lot of successfully compiled documents on other systems and they work everywhere! On Windows, Arch, Fedora and Ubuntu 16.04...
But they do not on Ubuntu 17.10. It says that **it can't find metrics file for lass0400 font.** I tried all the solutions for this problem, none of them works and I suppose it's Ubuntu problem because I install texlive-full from the official repo. And it works with English!

So here is how to get the same problem:

```
apt install gummi (or texmaker)
apt install texlive-full
```

And in LaTeX all you need is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
```

Could you check if you have the same problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do the following:

```
sudo apt-get install biber texlive-lang-cyrillic \
             fonts-cmu texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-extra \ 
             font-manager ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Here *font-manager* and *ttf-mscorefonts-installer* are not really needed.

With these dependencies I'm able to make LaTeX documents from RMarkdown on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

According to [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=artful&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=lassdc10.mf) *lassdc10.mf* is contained in `texlive-lang-cyrillic` package on 17.10.

**UPDATE 1:** I tried to build PDF from RMarkdown from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (beta of course) and it works as expected.

My LaTeX preamble is

```
\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\usepackage[fontsize=14pt]{scrextend}
```

You can try it on your 17.10.

**UPDATE 2:** I found nice simple beamer example on [this TeX.StackExchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367317) with Russian text. It compiles normally on 16.04 LTS, 17.10 and 18.04 LTS.

Comment: You mean in Russian?

Comment: Yes, in Russian and in English (`\usepackage[main=russian,english]{babel}`).

Comment: Well unfortunately it does not solve an issue on 17.10. Info I found on the Internet points out that this issue may sometimes be connected with incorrectly built Debian packages which create a mess with LaTeX folders. Do not know if this is only specific to my machine or is a common drawback. Hope someone tests the algorithm I described. And by the way ShareLatex without any problems compiles the same code. So it's 100% ubuntu problem

Comment: I updated my answer. My RMarkdown -> TeX -> PDF chain works as expected on 18.04 LTS (beta of course). I can't test plain LaTeX.

Comment: Thanks a lot to you! But even this does not solve the issue. If you know someone who has 17.10 - ask him to try. It's definitely something that many people might suffer from if it's a common issue!

Comment: Just simple question: which `arch` of Ubuntu do you have (x86_64 or i686)?

Comment: x86_64 is the one I am using

Comment: I just tried the aforementioned steps on clean installation of Ubuntu 17.10 (x86_64 as yours). I have no issues. Do you have any PPAs or third-party packages? Can you share your problematic TeX document (or its proof-of-bug draft :) )?

Comment: On 16.04 LTS, 17.10 and 18.04 LTS I can create simple beamer slide [from this TeX.StackExchange answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/367317).